# Optionally matching subgroup in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a SQL string I'm trying to match using PHP `preg_match_all` and I need to extract out the matches. It looks like this:

```
A BUNCH OF MEANINGLESS SQL And (Condition1 = 'thisvalue*' Or Condition1 = '8504577' Or Condition1 = 'somethingelse123*') And MORE MEANINGLESS SQL
```

I want to grab all those `Condition1 = X` parts and use them in a different area, but ONLY if they are in the larger sub-condition in parentheses and are connected by `Or`s.

My regex looks like this (https://www.regex101.com/r/gepdq9/3):

```
/(\((Condition1 = '[\dA-Za-z]+\*?'(\sOr\s)?)+\))/
```

It matches the larger sub-condition correctly, but for some reason the `matches[3]` item, which I think should be capturing all the `thisvalue*`, `8504577` and `somethingelse123*` values, is only capturing the last one.

How can I capture all of these matches?

Comment: Do you mean [**`(?:\(|(?!\A)\G(Condition1 = ('(?i)[[:alnum:]]+(?-i)\*?')( Or )?))`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/jOmglQ/1) ?

Comment: @revo-- that's very good, but I'd like to capture the entire subquery as well, so I can remove it from the original query.

Comment: Entire match is accessible by `$matches[0]` while working with output array of `preg_match_all`

Comment: Check out if [this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/690550) is of help.

Comment: @user101289 this question seems abandoned.  Did you find a resolution for your question?  if `bobble bubble`'s answer is what you used, please ask for the comment to be posted as an answer to be accepted.  If you used `revo`'s, let `revo` know the same.  If you used `Shai`'s please award the green tick.  Resolving this question will remove it from the unanswered questions list and spare users from wasting time solving an already solved question.

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample code that will work for your example:

```
$a="A BUNCH OF MEANINGLESS SQL And (Condition1 = 'thisvalue*' Or Condition1 = '8504577' Or Condition1 = 'somethingelse123') And MORE MEANINGLESS SQL";
if (preg_match('/\((Condition1.*( Or )?)\) /',$a,$m)){
    print $m[1]; /* Condition1 = 'thisvalue*' Or Condition1 = '8504577' Or Condition1 = 'somethingelse123' */
}
```

it looking for the "(Condition1" that follow with " Or " 1 or 0 times. the 0 times is for that last one that don't have any more " Or " after it. follow by a ")" to capture them all.
Next, because you are in PHP, if you want to remove all the " Or " and have each of the condition in its own var, do something like

```
$arr=explode(' Or ',$m[1]); /* "Condition1='thisvalue*'", "Condition1 = '8504577'",... */
```

If you want to break it all in regEx and see just the conditions values, you can try this:

```
$a="A BUNCH OF MEANINGLESS SQL And (Condition1 = 'thisvalue*' Or Condition1 = '8504577' Or Condition1 = 'somethingelse123') And MORE MEANINGLESS SQL";
if (preg_match_all("/Condition1 = '([^']+)'( Or )?/",$a,$m)){
    print_r($m[1]); /* [0] => thisvalue*    [1] => 8504577    [2] => somethingelse123 */
}
```